# ThinkScript to PineScript Conversion Question

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I am working on converting a ThinkScript indicator into PineScript. I am currently having problems with converting **ThinkScript's barNumber()** function to PineScript. I think I know what to use as its equivalent but I am not sure I understand the barNumber() even after reading the documentation and examples.

This indicator is basically used as an entry/exit indicator. I think what the code is doing by utilizing the barNumber() is removing the signal if a new signal is plotted, but if that new signal is invalidated then it reverts to the previous signal.

Here is the part of code I am confused with the first few defs have more meat behind them just it is irrelevant to explain them they should all return as floats (def stateUp through def linDev):

```
def bar = barNumber();

def stateUp;
def stateDn;
def atrCCI;
def price;
def linDev;

def CCI = if linDev == 0 
  then 0 
else (price - avg(price, length)) / linDev / 0.05;

def MT1 = if CCI > 0
  then max(MT1[1], hl2 - ATRCCI)
else (min(MT1[1], hl2 + ATRCCI)

def state = if close > ST and close > MT1 then StateUp
else if close < ST and close < MT1 then StateDn
else State[1];

def newState = HighestAll(if state <> state[1] then bar else 0);
```

The code uses a lot of conditional statements, here are some of the other usages for this code:

```
CSA = if bar >= newState then MT1 else Double.NaN;

signal = if bar >= newState and state == stateUp and. . .
```

Is there an easy way to approach this in PineScript?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The equivalent for thinkScript's [BarNumber()](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/Functions/Others/BarNumber) is Pine-Script's [bar_index](https://kodify.net/tradingview/bar-data/bar-number/).**

---

**thinkScript and Pine-Script both use a loop that represents the trading period range in effect. The BarNumber/bar_index value represents each measurement period that is being calculated through the loop.**

To compare this to other types of coding, you might consider something like `for bar_index in 0 to 10` for a trading period of 10 days, where `bar_index` would count from 0 through 9 (ie, it acts like the stereotypical `i` in a `for` loop).

The period the index represents could be a day, minute, tick, etc - whatever you set for your chart or calculations. And, note: *a "day" represents a "trading day", *not* a "calendar day".

**A confusing issue is: where do the bars start counting? The BarNumber() or bar_index starts at the *earliest* period of your time frame and counts *up* toward the most recent trading period of your time frame.** Eg, the bar_index of 0 might represent 10 days ago, while the bar_index of 9 might represent today.

Here's some example code from the [Kodify site (which provides Pine-Script tutorials)](https://kodify.net/tradingview/bar-data/bar-number/#example-count-bars-and-position-a-label-with-bar_index):

```
//@version=4
study("Example of bar_index variable", overlay=true)

// Make a new label once
var label myLabel = label.new(x=bar_index, y=high + tr,
     textcolor=color.white, color=color.blue)

// On the last bar, show the chart's bar count
if (barstate.islast)
    // Set the label content
    label.set_text(id=myLabel, text="Bars on\nthe chart:\n" +
         tostring(bar_index + 1))

    // Update the label's location
    label.set_x(id=myLabel, x=bar_index)
    label.set_y(id=myLabel, y=high + tr)
```

Note the `tostring(bar_index + 1))`. They're adding one because, remember, the index is zero-based, so an index that counts 0 to 9 is actually counting 10 bars.

---

I think the reason the BarNumber()/bar_index concept is confusing is because we also consider values the other way. For example, if we're comparing `close` to `close[1]`, that is the current period's `close` value compared to the previous period's `close` value (`close[1]`). That's *opposite* of the bar numbers! `close[1]` would actually have a *lower* bar number/index because it's from the period *before* `close`.

**When we use something like `close[1]`, the script is actually counting from the right to the left (most recent to earlier periods) - opposite of the BarNumber()/bar_index concept.**